# How to use beans in model attribute in Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, inversion-of-control

Hello Might be it's a silly Question But I am new in Spring frame work. Please help

**web.xml**

```
<display-name>demo name</display-name>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class>
</listener>
```

**applicationcontext.xml**

```
<bean id="loginInfo" class="com.saurabh.dto.LoginInfo"></bean>
<bean id="contactInfo" class="com.saurabh.dto.ContactInformation"></bean>

<bean id="userDTO" class="com.saurabh.dto.UserDTO" scope="request"  abstract="false">
    <property name="login" ref="loginInfo"></property>
    <property name="contact" ref="contactInfo"></property>
</bean>
```

**Controller**

```
 @Controller
 public class LogonController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/requestLogon.htm",method={RequestMethod.POST,RequestMethod.GET})
public String registerUser(@ModelAttribute("userDTO") UserDTO user, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        HttpSession session)throws Exception{
```

---

Now the problem is that in controller UserDTO user, I am getting login property as null but according to wiring I have inject it.  Please explain the issue..

Comment: But your `userDTO` in `registerUser` method is not the one you created in `applicationContext.xml` but its the one, you are using as model attribute to the corresponding form.

Comment: @Rahaman Thanks. This may be the Issue but what's the solution.? I'm Completely un aware.

Answer (score 0):

You may do better to create your UserDTO in a method annotated `@ModelAttribute` rather than specifying it in your Spring applicationContext.xml

```
@ModelAttribute("userDTO")
public UserDTO createModel() {
    UserDTO userDto = new UserDTO();
    userDto.setLogin(new LoginInfo());
    userDto.setContact(new ContactInformation());
    return userDto;
}
```

That will create and return a new UserDTO object per request - which Spring will bind the form data to.

Comment: OK This is just a solution but I need exact solution. Although this time also properties are getting populated but It's not using wiring and I want them to be used.

Answer (score 0):

`@ModelAttribute` on a method argument indicates the argument should be retrieved from the model. If not present in the model, the argument should be instantiated first and then added to the model.

So in your case, as UserDTO is not already in the model, Spring created a new object 'userDTO' which obviously has login variable with null value. This is similar to `UserDTO userDTO = new UserDTO();` the `userDTO.login` is null in this case.

And Will Keeling's answer is right. When the userDTO model is created with createdModel method (as he mentioned), Spring will do data binding and user object fields will be populated from **all request parameters that have matching names**. i.e. If you try with URL `/requestLogon.htm?login.username=ABC` (assuming you have username field in LoginInfo), the username will be bound correctly.

Comment: OK I agree with your answer and it helped me a lot to understand the foundation concept but what to do if I don't want to do this I want my data to be populated in beans which is wired in applicationcontext.xml so that I will also get the data injected by DI along with form data.

Comment: Saurabh, when do you want your data to be populated? On post of JSP form? If so, you need to use modelAttribute on your form element in jsp. You better separate your controller handler methods for GET and POST request. Then you will understand and debug it better.